# CSS buttons and stitch effect not working in IE

Tags: html, css

[My site here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) uses CSS buttons, but they're not working in IE and I can't figure out why as they're supposed to.

Here's the CSS:

```
/* Buttons: Common Style */
.big, .medium, .small{display: block;
text-align: center;
cursor:pointer;
font-family: sansus webissimo;
font-weight:normal !important;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 0 rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.8) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
}

/* Buttons: Sizes */
.big {width: 130px;padding:1px;font-size:25px;}
.medium {width: 80px;padding:3px;font-size:21px;}
.small {width: 68px;padding:3px;font-size:17px;}
.big:active, .medium:active, .small:active{box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);outline: 0 none;}
```

Also in IE, I'm using a [css stitching effect for the title headers and box titles](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood), but when the border radius isn't uniform ie. 'border-radius:6px' then the stitch effect doesn't work in IE only.

Here's the CSS:

```
/* TITLE BORDERS */
h1, h2, #left-nav .quickjump h2, .right-nav .banners h3, #left-nav .banners h3, h3.twitter, #datepicker .ui-widget-header, #datepicker .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header {margin-bottom:5px;font-family:'league gothic';font-size:26px;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px 12px;
background: #7B6E80;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #7B6E80, 1px 1px 3px 2px rgba(85, 85, 85, .5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #7B6E80, 1px 1px 3px 2px rgba(85, 85, 85, .5);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #7B6E80, 1px 1px 3px 2px rgba(85, 85, 85, .5);
color: white;
border: 1px dashed #ddd;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #222222;
border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
line-height: 1.3;
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done lots of research and concluded they're just IE bugs, so the answer is there's no answer.

Also for the CSS Buttons, the filter needed adjusting for IE.

Answer (score 0):

The stitching effect is partially created by box-shadow, a property not supported by IE<9

Comment: Dude it's just a dashed border type, who said it uses `box-shadow`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's IE9 I'm checking in, but if you read it says it only happens when the border radius isn't uniform, ie 'border-radius 6px 6px 0 0;'. Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: @LaurenBuckley - Yes, that is odd. If you look very closely, it does still work, but not the desired effect. If you make the border thicker (2px) on these you can see it better, but that gives you another set of aesthetic issues to deal with. For all intents and purposes it looks like an IE Bug (who would've thunk it?)

Comment: Yep, I did that but the 2px doesn't jive. Nightmare browser. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Adam - any ideas about the buttons?